# How can I get int values from the change dictionary in KVO method observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

I am observing changes in the `rate` property of an AVPlayer by calling the following method on it like so:

```
addObserver:sharedPlayerManagerInstance
 forKeyPath:@"rate"
    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
    context:0];
```

The `change` dictionary I get back from `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` is therefore:

```
change = { kind: 1,
            new: 1,
            old: 0 }
```

I checked the class of each value, and it turns out to be __NSCFNumber. However, when I try to convert `[change objectForKey:@"new"]` or `[change objectForKey:@"old"]` into an int, NSInteger, NSNumber, even tried NSString, etc, it works for "old", but it gives me a parsing error for the "new":

```
error: expected a type
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

I really need to compare them, and I can't figure it out. Could this be a bug in iOS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Objective C

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
NSNumber * newValue = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
NSInteger integerValue = newValue.integerValue;
int intValue = newValue.intValue;
}
```

Swift

```
   override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if let newValue = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as? NSNumber{
            let intvalue = newValue.intValue //To int
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can I do this in objective-c?

Comment: @Amy See what I udpate

Comment: Thanks! Using keys NSKeyValueChangeNewKey and NSKeyValueChangeOldKey worked for me. I was able to compare the NSNumbers with isEqual:

However, for anyone in the future struggling with this, the conversion of the NSNumber to NSInteger or int didn't work for me. Keeping it as NSNumber is fine though.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3:**

```
if let newValue = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? NSNumber {
     // Do stuff
}
```